# How to Scroll a dropdown-menu programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

It will be easier to explain what I want to do with images.

This is the dropdown: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqp1i.png)

In "composicion_estadistica" there are collapsed fields that expand when you click on it.
The problem is that when I click it I get this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wk3P.png)

The expanded fields dont show and you need to scroll down to see them. I want that when the fields are expanded it automatically scrolls down so you can see the new fields.

In this case scrolling to the end of the dropdown-menu would be good enough, but that may not always be the case, is it possible to scroll down to a specific location? 
For example: If 10 new fields are expanded, I want to scroll down 10 lines.

Hope I explained myself well.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-filtro btnWidget" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Agregar Orden  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:300px;">
    <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 30px; cursor: pointer;" ng-repeat="field in controller.fields">
        {{field.name}}
    </li>

    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header" style="padding: 3px 10px; font-weight: bold; cursor: default;" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">Relaciones</li>

    <ng-repeat ng-repeat="relacion in controller.relaciones" ng-init="relacion.show = false">
        <li class="dropdown-header" style="padding: 3px 20px; font-weight: bold; cursor: default;" ng-click="relacion.show = !relacion.show; $event.stopPropagation();">
            <span class="" ng-class="{'caret-right': !relacion.show, 'caret-bottom': relacion.show}"></span>
            {{relacion.name}}
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 30px; cursor: pointer;" ng-repeat="field in relacion.fields" ng-show="relacion.mostrar">
            {{field.name}}
        </li>
    </ng-repeat>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "angular-scroll-glue" :
An AngularJs directive that automatically scrolls to the bottom of an element on changes in its scope.

Hope it will help.
source: https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue